# get the desired resultset value which could take hours to show up in the table

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, activemq-classic, spring-jdbc

The method `processFebMessage` in one of my springboot class sends the message obtained from the `test` queue from Apache ActiveMQ MOM to the `sendMessage` method so that I can retrieve the value of `REQUEST_STATUS` column from the `emp.data_request` table as shown in the method of `RequestDaoImpl` class below in the following line of code : `System.out.println(rs.getString("REQUEST_STATUS"));`

**Little Info regarding `REQUEST_STATUS`:**

This column basically shows the running status of some already started stored procedure.The different `REQUEST_STATUS` values are `RUNNING`, `COMPLETE`, `ERRONEOUS`

**What's happening right now:**

My springboot app is deployed as WAR on Apache tomcat. So, right now it keeps on grabbing messages from the queue and this line`System.out.println(rs.getString("REQUEST_STATUS"));`
in the code  prints `RUNNING` for each of the messages. In the database table,after sometime (it could be few mins or maybe hours) it changes to `COMPLETE` by that time my application has 
already moved ahead and processed all the messages from the queue.

I am wondering what's the best approach to keep on checking the status from the table again and again until it changes to `COMPLETE` ?Basically, in simple terms, I want to keep calling 
this line of code `rs.getString("REQUEST_STATUS")` until I see `COMPLETE`. After this, I want to perform some SELECT operations on 4 different tables to 
get select the data and convert it into CSV and put it somewhere on the server.

```
@JmsListener(destination = "test")
    public void processFebMessage(String message) throws DaoException {

        System.out.println("Message Retrieved is:" +message);

        try {

        RequestDao requestDao = (RequestDao) context.getBean("requestDao");
        requestDao.sendMessage(message);

        }
        catch(Throwable th){
            th.printStackTrace();   

        }

     }
```

**RequestDao**

```
public interface RequestDao {

    public void sendMessage(String msg) throws DaoException;

}
```

**Method implementation inside RequestDaoImpl class:**

```
@Override
    public void sendMessage(String msg) throws DaoException {

        DataSource ds = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {

               ds = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource();
               conn = ds.getConnection();   

               pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select REQUEST_STATUS from  emp.data_request where id=?");
                pstmt.setString(1,msg);
                rs = pstmt.executeQuery();  
                rs.next();

                System.out.println("The status received is as follows:");

                System.out.println(rs.getString("REQUEST_STATUS"));
                }
            catch(Throwable th) {
                //some code
            }
            finally {
                //some code
            }   



    }
```

Let me know if I can answer some questions. Looping over Thread.sleep somehow comes to my mind but I've read that it's not a good practice because if the `REQUEST_STATUS` changes to `COMPLETE` in few minutes and I have paused the thread for 30 minutes, it won't make much sense.

**Follow up questions based on Matt's reply:**

1. I am sending 10 messages now based on the following criteria ([using exact same criteria mentioned in the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/delay-and-schedule-message-delivery.html)):

[image]

2. Understood that my consuming app will invoke `REQUEST_STATUS`.
3. When `status != COMPLETED or ERRONEOUS`, you mentioned `you register a new scheduled message to run again in x time.` My question is, the producer has already sent or in the process of sending 10 messages during this time. Isn't it like the consumer will automatically, keep on consuming all the messages from the Queue one by one? This is what I have observed. The thing that is confusing to me is when you say `register a new scheduled message to run again in x time`. I mean, if I am not wrong, there is no way in the consumer I can explicitly specify to register a new scheduled message, right?
4. Similarly, I am little bit confused when you say `Once the status is COMPLETED, you do not register a scheduled message`. I mean it completely makes sense theoretically but I am wondering, if in ActiveMQ, there are any specific instructions to follow to avoid registering a scheduled message if my status is `COMPLETED`?But programmatically, I could `break` from the loop once I see the status as `COMPLETED`. Is this what you were referring to?

Comment: Sleeping is not a good idea. Try having the message to be redelivered at a later time so you can try it again.

Comment: I see.  Actually, the messages are user-driven. I mean, in my publisher spring-boot app, when an Ajax call hits the REST controller, a stored procedure is called and this stored procedure generates a new unique message which is sent to the ActiveMQ. Any ideas, how should I approach in this scenario? Not sure how I can have the message redelivered in this case.

Comment: I don't use ActiveMQ, so I have to go by intuition (and a bit of scavenging on their site), but as the consumer of a message you can trigger redelivery (with a delay dictated by a redelivery policy), so you can try again later.

Comment: Ok. So it looks like even though the message has been consumed by the consumer and does not exist in the queue, it would somehow be possible for the ActiveMQ to redeliver the message again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a scheduled message.

Code the process flow like this:

1. Send message to the queue with a schedule to run one (1) time in x time period
2. Your consuming app receives the message to invoke the REQUEST_STATUS
3. In your method, if the status != COMPLETED or ERRONEOUS, you register a new scheduled message to run again in x time.
4. Once the status is COMPLETED, you do not register a scheduled message
5. Note: you should add a header to the message provide a counter for max number of times to check, to prevent an infinite loop if there is a problem with a process that never breaks out of 'RUNNING' status.

[ActiveMQ Scheduled Message](http://activemq.apache.org/delay-and-schedule-message-delivery.html)

Comment: Thanks. So, I have my publisher based springboot app deployed separately. If the app sends a scheduled message which is user driven, and if `status != COMPLETED or ERRONEOUS` on consumer side, then can my consumer (a different springboot app) be able to re-register message to run x-time? I am wondering if it needs to communicate with the publisher somehow in this scenario?

Comment: Nope, no need to coordinate. It is a really sweet pattern to be async and decoupled like that. In your case, register one-time scheduled messages-- no repeat, no cron.

Comment: Hey @Matt Pavlowich, Quick question: I am able to receive the messages with timer basically with an initial delay, and the repeat delivery 10 times, waiting 10 seconds between each re-delivery as mentioned in the documentation http://activemq.apache.org/delay-and-schedule-message-delivery.html. Could you tell me how do I stop receiving messages from the queue on consumer side if I want to stop at 5th message (if my status is COMPLETED at 5th message)? I couldn't find any configuration related details in the documentation. Thanks again.

Comment: Edited answer to clarify.. did that clear it up?  Register a message to deliver 1 time.. every time you check and status is not completed.. register a new scheduled message.  Once status is ok, you do not need to register a message.

Comment: I understood what you are saying but wanted to clarify more. I updated my post with the questions. Please take a look. Thanks for your time. Appreciated.

Comment: Why are you sending 10 messages?  I suggest sending 1 message with no repeat. If the status is done on the first message, no need to schedule a second message or cancel the rest!

Comment: Ok.So you are saying that if I send one message, the JMSListner(in my `RequestDaoImpl `) will keep on looking for this condition  `if (status = COMPLETED)` even if it's going to take hours ?

Comment: No.. register the first scheduled message to check in x hours.. then when your JMSListener receives the scheduled message.. if the status != COMPLETE.. register a NEW scheduled message to deliver to the JMSListener again in :05 minutes... repeat until completed.

Comment: Ok so this thing `register the first scheduled message to check in x hours` is achieved by a completely separate spring-boot app which sends out message to the broker based on user interaction with the app. I can check for `status != COMPLETE` in my consumer app (separate spring boot app). Based on whether the status is complete or not which can be known only in consumer app, I am still not clear how I can schedule a new message to deliver to JMSListner again since there is no communication between publisher and consumer apps deployed as WAR on the server.

Comment: Continued...   Are you saying that I should have the same logic of registering a NEW message in my consumer app as well if I see `status != COMPLETE` ?By same logic, I mean the steps I mentioned in my #1 starting with this line `MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination)`.P.S. I understood what your are saying theoritically, just trying to fit your explanation in the context of my problem. Thanks

Comment: Yes! Part of the consumer app's technical requirements would become 'if status is not complete, register a scheduled message to check again'.